# Orbeon 4.2 databound-select1 doesn't accept resource

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I've made an XBL component for entering an address. In that XBL component, I used `databound-select1` fields in a way similar to what is done in `databound-select1-unittest.xhtml`.

In the beginning, for simplicity, I used a static XML file accessible over http as a resource. But after I changed the resource URL to a service URL, the `databound-select1` doesn't show items anymore. To locate the problem I made a form with two databound-select1 fields and both resources. But the result was the same.

I tested the service output and file output in the XForms Inspector by adding instances, which take their source from different resources, to the form, and the inspector shows both instances without problems.

(I use Form Builder. The service which returns items is behind HTTPS. `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`.)

Comment: Have you tried to simplify the problem, e.g. is the problem the same with HTTP or does it only happen with HTTPS? Also, does this happen when the `databound-select1` control is used directly, not inside one of your XBL component? Once you have simplified the issue as much as you can, could you post a minimal example that we can use to reproduce it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a wrong `Content-Type`.

When I started making a sample form on a separate orbeon I got a error message in the log:

**Body received with non-XML media type for replace="instance": text/html**

Changing the service response Content-Type to `application/xml` solved the problem.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!